# How do I use ResponseEntity<Mono<String>> to do a get call via webclient?

Tags: get, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Documentaion says:-

ResponseEntity<Mono> or ResponseEntity<Flux> -- this makes the response status and headers known immediately while the body is provided asynchronously at a later point. Whether the body is Mono or Flux depends on how many values the response has.

My usecase is I want the headers right away so that I can do some processes while I wait for the body.

Can anyone help me with a method that would make use of this ?

Comment: This is about response. It means while building response in your endpoint you could provide headers immediately and for body specify `Mono` or `Flux` - `return ResponseEntity.ok().header("key","value").body(mono)`.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks Alex.